# jQuery.load without server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writting a simply HTML5 file which I want to use locally in order to get access to and display different HTML5 documents with educational information.

In short: I have some different word documents with my personal summaries (college, courses, notes, etc) that I've been developing through years and now I'm looking to develop that browser application with which I'd like to be able to navigate through these word documents (previously converted into HTML5 format).

That browser application would be an index.html page with a navbar menu (let's say) with different links which will display in the index.html (inside a specific div) the different HTML5 files (remmember that word documents previously converted).

Since I do not want to use any server (I want to execute my application in any computer, offline) I tried using jQuery load() function as it's shown:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#content").load('/pages/example2');
});
```

It works fine in a server but does not without server.

Is there anyway to do what I want to? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your attention.
Please, keep in mind I'm not a professional developer and this is my first post in a develop forum.

Kind regards.

Comment: No, your assets must be served; Javascript doesn't have access to the local file system for obvious security reasons.

Comment: There are several free web servers you can use on your local machine. Windows still comes with [IIS](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/install-and-setup-a-website-in-iis-on-windows-10/) (you may still even be able to download it from MS if your version does not include it as standard, I've not tried in a while), or there's [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi).

Comment: Thank you both for your quick answers. @Rory McCrossan, what if I want to run this "app" in any PC? That PC would need to have Apache runing I guess, haven't it? Anyway, do you know or could you suggest me another way to develot such an app?

Comment: Yes, you will need a webserver running. There's no other way to reliably test AJAX requests locally. The two links above solve the issue and can be configured and running within 5 minutes